# What do we mean by 'Variability in Web Services'?

Tags: web-services, soa, cloud

In the era of **SOA** and **Cloud Computing**, we often hear the term "Variability in Web Services". I think it means how an implemented web service can be modified to the new requirements of user or geography.

Still what would be a good definition of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it means that not all of the Web Services will output the same output, thus if you are building an application that uses that output you may have to change it somehow...

The web services could change or update, which may cause problems to some users.